# Hibernate native query with positional parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I wrote native sql query instead of using hql and faced with roblem

**Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1**

```
<sql-query name="GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION">
    <![CDATA[
        select TEST.TEST_ID as testId, TEST.VERSION_ID as versionId,
        PASSED_TEST.RESULT as userResult,
        PASSED_TEST.TIME_COMPLITED as timeComplited,
        sum(COMPLEXITY) as maxTestResult from QUESTION
        JOIN TEST_QUESTION ON QUESTION.QUESTION_ID = TEST_QUESTION.QUESTION_ID
        JOIN TEST ON TEST.TEST_ID=TEST_QUESTION.TEST_ID
        JOIN PASSED_TEST ON TEST.TEST_ID=PASSED_TEST.TEST_ID
        AND TEST.VERSION_ID=PASSED_TEST.VERSION_ID
        WHERE TEST.SUBJECT_ID = ?
        AND PASSED_TEST.USER_ID = ?
        GROUP BY PASSED_TEST.TEST_EVENT_ID
        ]]>
    </sql-query>
```

And DAO

```
return session
                .createSQLQuery(GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION_NAME_QUERY)
                .addScalar(TEST_ID_RESULT_PARAM, StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
                .addScalar(VERSION_ID_RESULT_PARAM, StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
                .addScalar(USER_RESULT_PARAM, StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
                .addScalar(MAX_TEST_RESULT_PARAM, StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE)
                .addScalar(TIME_COMPLITED_RESULT_PARAM, StandardBasicTypes.DATE)
                .setParameter(0, subjectId)
                .setParameter(1, userId)
                .setResultTransformer(
                        Transformers.aliasToBean(PassedTestStatistic.class))
                .list();
```

I read that `//JPA specification. Only positional parameter binding may be portably used for native queries.` And that hibernate use 0 as first index.

**stacktrace**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:416)
    at by.bsuir.testapp.database.hibernate.PassedTestHibernateDAO.getDataForPassedTestStatisticGraph(PassedTestHibernateDAO.java:73)
    at by.bsuir.testapp.service.PassedTestServiceImpl.getDataForPassedTestStatisticGraph(PassedTestServiceImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy28.getDataForPassedTestStatisticGraph(Unknown Source)
    at by.bsuir.testapp.controller.StatisticPassedTest.createLinearModel(StatisticPassedTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
```

**//UPDATE**

Interesting, when I set in query number values

```
WHERE TEST.SUBJECT_ID = 1
        AND PASSED_TEST.USER_ID = 1
```

I get

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION' at line 1
```

But in MySQL I get sucessful result.

How I can decide this problem?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @JB Nizet Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace.

Comment: What version of hibernate?

Comment: @Ray Did you try changing the createSQLQuery to getNamedQuery as suggested in one of the answers?  I think this is important.

Comment: @schtever doesn't matter that it's sql query  not hql?

Answer (score 7):

You call

```
session.createSQLQuery
```

but I believe you need to call

```
session.getNamedQuery
```

when using a named query.

Answer (score 2):

Please check

```
.setParameter(1, subjectId)
.setParameter(2, userId)
```

as the exception trace says that ordinal parameters are 1-based!

Comment: the exception seems to be misleading. It is actually 0 based

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using named parameter instead of providing positional parameter.

For eg.

```
session
  .createSQLQuery("update table1 set variable = variable + 1 where id = :id")
  .setParameter("id", someId)
  .executeUpdate();
```

Native SQL queries support positional as well as named parameters.

Please read Named SQL queries in : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930

Comment: I try with positional parameters from 0, also from 1, and with named also.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source

```
createSQLQuery(GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION_NAME_QUERY)
```

you must have variable pointing to a string containing the actual name of the native query like so:

```
GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION_NAME_QUERY = "GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION"
```

The error you get here:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION' at line 1
```

Indicates that createSqlQuery isn't finding your native query by name but is instead trying to execute the name "GET_ARRAY_MAX_POINT_QUESTION" as raw SQL just as if you'd put in s.createSqlQuery("Select * from...") If you look at the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html), you will see that in order to look up a named query, even a native one, you still have to use getNamedQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For those who googled the error message:
Got this error when I had no mapping for a class of interest at all. Mapping solved the problem.